# How can I get Multiple HashSet with ServiceStack Redis Client

Tags: redis, servicestack

I want to get Multiple HashSet. There is

```
public HashSet<string> GetAllItemsFromSet (string setId){ ....}
```

I need

```
public HashSet<string>[] GetAllItemsFromSets (string[] setIds)
```

How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API doesn't exist on the RedisClient and there is no specific Redis server operation for this task so you have to add extend the Redis client yourself, which you can do easily with an Extension method, e.g:

```
public static class RedisClientExtensions {
   public static HashSet<string>[] GetAllItemsFromSets(this IRedisClient client, 
       string[] setIds)
   {
       return setIds.Select(x => client.GetAllItemsFromSet(x)).ToArray();
   }
}
```

Comment: I have already written similar.But is it possible to achieve this with single request? Like this  https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/blob/master/src/RedisStackOverflow/RedisStackOverflow.ServiceInterface/IRepository.cs#L180

Comment: Yeah you can use a Transaction or Pipeline but then you'd have to handle all the async callbacks and merge the results. You may also want to return a Dictionary so you can match up the setIds with the results.